# sql query to find customers whose rental days are more than or equal to 10 days

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to find every customers whose rental days are equal to greater than 10days. My solution is not giving me any syntax error but it gives incorrect total number of customers count. Here is my solution:

```
with rental_history as (
   select
      customer_id
      ,rental_date
      ,return_date
      ,rental_date + interval '10 day' as ban_date
      ,coalesce(return_date, now())-rental_date as days_out
   from rental
)
select count(*) as number_of_lost_rentals
from rental_history where days_out >= interval '10 day'
```

I am getting incorrect count and see below error:

[image]

Here is the database schema:

[image]

Comment: How the rental days will be calculated?

Comment: Please explain or better yet show with data *why* current results are incorrect. No results? Missing data? Over/under counting?

Comment: It is return_date - rental_date. i.e. `(return_date, now())-rental_date`

Comment: @Parfait I need to find total number of customers whose rental days are greater than 10days and I have also edited the question so that you can understand.

Comment: @Parfait added error message that I am getting which states that count is incorrect.

Comment: Curious, how did that testing error raise? From Postgres, application code, other? Or is this coursework where answer is known.

Comment: Its a course work

Comment: Got it and what of these numbers is your result? Are you over or under counting?

Comment: I am undercounting, correct result is 6294

Answer (score 0):

For these type of scenarios you need to understand 2 things:

1. if you subtract 2 dates it will return difference in days as `Integer`
2. If you subtract 2 timestamp, it will return the difference in `interval`.

what I understood from your question and comments and considering your `return_date` and `rental_date` fields are `timestamp`, you should write your query like this:

```
select 
count(*) 
from rental 
where return_date::date - rental_date::date>=10
```

But above will give the results from all time. If you want count of clients whose pending rental days are greater than equal to 10 days from today then try like this:

```
select 
count(*) 
from rental 
where current_date - rental_date::date>=10 and
```

Comment: can you explain what is incorrect? You want difference between return_date and rental_date or something else

Comment: @RunSmeagolRun, same exact incorrect testing error? Need to know how testing is calculated. This is one way to calculate difference between two dates in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count customers who have a rental exceeding 10 days, then:

```
select count(distinct customer_id)
from rental
where rental_date <= coalesce(return_date, current_date) - interval 10 'day';
```

If you want to count the days across *all rentals* for a customer -- which is how I would interpret the question -- then you need aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (select customer_id,
             sum( (coalesce(return_date, current_date) - rental_date) )::int as num_days
      from rental r
      group by customer_id
     ) c
where num_days >= 10;
```

Note:  It is also unclear from your question if someone who rents on 2020-09-01 and returns on 2020-09-01 counts as 1 day or 2 days.

Comment: What do you mean by `where rental r` in your solution? Because I am getting syntax error for that

Comment: @RunSmeagolRun . . . That should not be there, a typo.